# Table Select Error with Mail Merge from Excel to word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, mailmerge

First off here is my code.

```
Sub RunMerge()
' Word constants

Dim wd As Object
Dim wdocSource As Object

Dim strWorkbookName As String

On Error Resume Next
Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If wd Is Nothing Then
    Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Set wdocSource = wd.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\AAFCAAC-#4077508-v1-AAFC-FFPB-COPE-SATD-_AgriInnovation_Draft_Survey_Instructions_189318.doc")

strWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "MD.xlsm"

wdocSource.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters

wdocSource.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
        Name:=strWorkbookName, _
        AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
        Revert:=False, _
        Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
        Connection:="Data Source=" & strWorkbookName, _
        SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM 'Mail Merge Data$'"

With wdocSource.MailMerge
    .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
    .SuppressBlankLines = True
    With .DataSource
        .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
        .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
    End With
    .Execute Pause:=False
End With

wd.Visible = True
wdocSource.Close SaveChanges:=False

Set wdocSource = Nothing
Set wd = Nothing

End Sub
```

I'm trying to get a mail merge going from excel to word. My problem (I believe) is with SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM 'Mail Merge Data$'" for when I run my code excel goes into limbo waiting for word. When I go into my task manager I see word is stuck on selecting a table. There are no options in the table select menu and the designated workbook is only the path of my workbook with .xls appended to the end. If I remove the SQLStatement line the same thing happens but the select table is populated with the sheets and name ranges in my workbook. I'm hoping that this is a minor error or a typo on my part.

Comment: Just to give a little more information. If I remove the SQLStatement line and go to my task manager to select the "table select" process (it can only be selected using the task manager) and choose the right sheet then the rest of the program runs smoothly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you removed additional quotation marks which are required in your situation. Your SQL statement should rather looks like:

```
SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `'Mail Merge Data$'`"
```

You could also try with this code:

```
SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [Mail Merge Data$]"
```