# Connect multiple mail merge word file templates to the same data source automatically

Tags: python, excel, for-loop, ms-word, mailmerge

I am trying to create a python script that would do the following :

1. Select some word file (mail merge) templates using tkinter askopenfilenames
2. Select an excel file data source using tkinter filedialog askopenfilename
3. Connect every word file selected to the specified excel file.

I need help with the third step.

Also, I would love to know if there is a better approach for the above task.

Code written so far :

```
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
excel_file= fd.askopenfilename()
templates = fd.askopenfilenames()
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by connect? would you like a hyperlink or a full document?

Comment: Let me rephrase : I want to fill the word template files based on the contents of the same source excel file.

Comment: So you want to import a table like format from an excel file into the word file, but you also want to keep track of changes in the excel file, i.e. any change to the excel file will update in the word file?   Any specific reason for using python? you can do it all in VBA I think.

Comment: Not quite. Say eg that I have an Excel column with the values Name1, Name2,Name3 etc. Say that the first word template is : Dear name_var how are you doing?, the second word template is : Hello name_var, how are you?. I want to replace the namevar mergefield with the values of the excel column Name1,Name2,Name3 for each of the word template files. I know very little of VBA and would like to connectt the script with another python script.

Comment: So you have a number of word templates each having an excel spread sheet that you want to use mail merge function on.

Comment: Close but not quite. The excel spread sheet is the same for all the word files.

Comment: It all makes sense now that I have re-read your question apologies. With regards to VBA it seems like you might be able to do something like in this code here {https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819876/table-select-error-with-mail-merge-from-excel-to-word}, where you would create a excel sheet with a dashboard and a list of all the word documents you want to loop through.

Comment: No problem, thank you very much for your input. The truth is that I would prefer a pythonic approach. Would you happen to know something of that kind? Regardless, thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: Commenting for a pythonic approach.

Comment: If you don't mind installing a new module (pywin32), then look at this video.  https://youtu.be/Zh7L9GmHihQ
You will need to add a loop to go through each of the word documents you want.

Comment: Thank you very much, I believe this is what I needed! I will get back to you soon to let you know if this indeed solves my problem.